# Angularjs - Updating multiple instances of the same controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

**My problem:** I have multiple instances a controller in my site. When I update 'x', only the current instance/div gets updated.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/evgahe2u/ (simplified example, each ng-controller is in its own view.)

HTML

```
<!-- this is a simplified example -->
<div ng-app="myApp">
       <!-- this is in view1.html -->
        <div ng-controller="myController">
                <input type="text" ng-model="x" /> {{x}}
        </div>
        <!-- this is in view2.html -->
        <div ng-controller="myController">
                <input type="text" ng-model="x" /> {{x}}
        </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.x = 'test';
});
```

**My question:** How can I have it so when I update View1.html's X value, it will then update view2.html's view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty easy.

According to me the best way to do this is to create a factory.

Let's say factory X and let's create two controllers for both views:

```
myApp.controller('1Ctrl', function($scope, x) {
  $scope.x = x.x;
});

myApp.controller('2Ctrl', function($scope, x) {
  $scope.x = x.x;
});

myApp.factory('x', function() {
  return {
    x: 'value'
  };
});
```

Full Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knjbncwz/)

Now if X is updated it will update in both controllers, because of the properties of an object. Both x'es on both scopes are the same x.

Comment: using a service is a good idea as well, personally, I thought broadcast was the way to go

Comment: i think broadcast makes your code confusing, its easier to reproduce a factory in other controllers as well, than to plug broadcast and $on events everywhere

Comment: either way, both approaches work, I like yours as it's more reusable. but I like mine as it's a simple event you can capture in any controller and quite easy to understand, and you don't need to create a service just to share data.

Comment: @ZackArgyle That looks like the way to handle it. Thanks EliteOctagon and Pepijn. I will re-architect my controller now.

Answer (score 1):

Broadcast from rootScope

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("changeXevent", dataToSend);
```

then handle it with an $on in the controller.

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $rootScope) { // inject rootscope
    $scope.x = 'test';

    // watch for event
    $scope.$on('changeXevent', function(event, data){
         $scope.x = data;
    });

    // watch for changes on x
    $scope.$watch('x', function(newValue, oldValue){
        if(newVal !== oldVal)
            $rootScope.$broadcast('changeXevent', $scope.x);
    });

});
```

Comment: I'll elaborate a little more.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I thought the controllers were in the same scope. But it looks like they don't share scope at all.

Comment: They don't share a scope indeed, but i would advise against using the same controller twice on a page, maybe it's better to look at a directive where you can share scopes.

Comment: No they do not share scope, and i think @Pepijn makes a point about not working, but you can account for that by doing value checks.