# Angular.js: How to update data from one HTML to other HTML which uses same controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have following 2 html pages

**1. home.html**

```
<div data-ng-controller="userComments">

         <Will display all the comments>

</div>
```

**2. comments.html**

```
<div data-ng-controller="userComments">

         <Have a comment box and submit button. 
         Submit button calls submit() function on ng-click>

</div>
```

where `comments.html` is pop-up which is initiated from the home page.
And **controller**

```
    .controller('userComment',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.title = 'User Comment';
        $scope.comments = <db call>
        $scope.cmt = '';
        $scope.submit = function(){
            console.log("comment just entered", $scope.cmt);
            $scope.comments = $scope.comments.concat($scope.cmt);
            console.log("Updated Comments", $scope.comments);
            };
    }])
```

New comments need to be updated automatically in the `home.html` as well. What should i do to accomplish that?

Thanks

**Update:**

when the comments are added in the `comment.html` page, `ng-click` triggers `submit` function, `$scope.comments` gets updated with the new comment, but what should i do to get the updated comments in the `home.html` too?

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with your current implementation as described? Seeing as how the comments are all managed in the same controller, it's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: What do you mean by "2 html pages"? Do you mean that you have two partials (with `ng-include`, for example)? Do you mean, that you could open 2 pages in two browser tabs side-by-side and see the updates in one immediately appear in the other? Or are these 2 different pages generated by your backend server and both have to have the comments?

Comment: So, you storage then on localstorage or use some database? Or you want that just live?

You need to submit to your database or localstorage if you use then.

Comment: @NathanTaylor: Thank you. I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: @NewDev: `comments.html` is a pop-up initiated from some where `home.html`. If comments entered and submitted, it should get updated in the `home.html` too. Sorry. I thought I confused every one with not stating properly. Will update the question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the same controller on different views, different instances of the controller are created. You'll need a factory or service to store and share data between views.

So in your case, you'll want a comments factory, something like

```
myApp.factory('commentsService', function() {
  return {
    comments: []
  };
});
```

Then in your controller:

```
.controller('userComment',['$scope', 'commentsService', function($scope, commentsService){
    $scope.title = 'User Comment';
    $scope.comments = commentsService.comments;
    $scope.cmt = '';
    $scope.submit = function(){
        console.log("comment just entered", $scope.cmt);
        $scope.comments = $scope.comments.concat($scope.cmt);
        // store the comments for use across views
        commentsService.comments = $scope.comments;
        console.log("Updated Comments", $scope.comments);
        };
}])
```

You can build out the comments service to also make the db call, as that is an angular best practice (don't fetch external data from controllers, do it from factory/service). You'd build a method called getComments() or something, then call that from the controller.

See:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

[Angularjs - Updating multiple instances of the same controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895567/angularjs-updating-multiple-instances-of-the-same-controller)

Answer (score 1):

Angularjs provides two-way binding so inserting

```
<div data-ng-controller="userComments">
         {{comments}}
</div>
```

would update comments.
To have same data in entire application( that one defined by ng-app directive ), define a **service**:

- You can inject service to whatever controller
- Service data is the same in entire application.

Create service using service method of module.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]).service('myService', function() { 
    this.comments = [];
    });
```

Injecting service to controller:

```
.controller('MyController',['myService',function(myService){
this.addComments = function(data){
myService.comments.push(data);
}
this.getComments = function(){
return myService.comments;
};
}]);
```

This would keep data same across aplication, and you can also inject this service to another controllers.

Invoke later controller, which uses service:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as mc">
    {{mc.getComments()}}
</div>
```

and in another view, set:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as mc">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myComm"/>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="mc.addComment(myComm)" value="Add comment"></button>
</div>
```

It sets service with new comment. myComm is variable. 
ng-model is set with input text, user entered, and ng-click attribute executes on user click.

As final word, there are services provided with angular. 
There is $http for network calls, $timeout for invoking things after specific time. You can use them for specific operations and also you can have your own services.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the events bundled in AngularJS in order to communicate the two instances. So every time the comments array has changes, you can trigger an custom event that the other controller listens and then update the comments array of the other controller.